# What's wrong with my framebuffer?

Tags: c++, opengl, framebuffer

I'm creating a framebuffer object to be my gbuffer for deferred shading.  I mainly learned from http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/, and modified to be a little more...  sane.  Here's the source code where I create the framebuffer:

```
/* Create the FBO */
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

/* Create the gbuffer textures */
glGenTextures(GBUFFER_NUM_TEXTURES, tex);

/* Create the color buffer */
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex[GBUFFER_COLOR]);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex[GBUFFER_COLOR], 0);

/* Create the normal buffer */
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex[GBUFFER_NORMAL]);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RG16F, width, height, 0, GL_RG, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex[GBUFFER_NORMAL], 0);

/* Create the depth-stencil buffer */
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex[GBUFFER_DEPTH_STENCIL]);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, width, height, 0, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex[GBUFFER_DEPTH_STENCIL], 0);

GLenum drawBuffers[] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1};
glDrawBuffers(2, drawBuffers);
glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);

/* Check for errors */
GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{
    error("In GBuffer::init():\n");
    errormore("Failed to create Framebuffer, status: 0x%x\n", status);
    fbo = 0;
    return;
}

// restore default FBO
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

When I run this, however, status returns `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT`.  If it's not clear, I'm trying to create 3 gbuffers:

- a 32-bit RGBA color buffer (I'd use 24-bit but I'm scared of alignment penalties),
- a 32-bit RG normal buffer (each component using a 16-bit float, but I might get away with a signed short?)
- a 24-bit Depth buffer packed with an 8-bit Stencil buffer
- (total of 96 bits, or 12 bytes)

Possible problem areas that I can see might be using GL_FLOAT for the normal buffer, and GL_FLOAT for the depth-stencil buffer.  I'd imagine GL_HALF_FLOAT would be more appropriate for normals, but that's not on the list of types that I can use with glTexImage2D.  Similarly, I have no idea what type is most appropriate to use for a depth-stencil buffer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For depth stencil texture, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8 seems more appropriate that GL_FLOAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `GL_FLOAT` is *mostly* irrelevant, since no pixel transfer actually happens.

You can supply anything you want there as long as it is a meaningful data type. While no pixel transfer happens when you pass `NULL` for data, GL still validates the pixel transfer data type against the set of valid types and will raise an error if you do something wrong. To that end, if it raises an error the texture will be incomplete and thus cannot be used as an FBO attachment.

Here is where the problem lies, `GL_FLOAT` is not a meaningful data type for pixel transfer into a packed `GL_DEPTH_STENCIL` image format... it expects a packed data type such as `GL_UNSIGED_INT_24_8` or something really exotic like `GL_FLOAT_32_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8_REV​` (64-bit packed Floating-Point Depth + Stencil format).

In any event, there are actually two components that need to be packed into your data type. `GL_FLOAT` can only describe one of the two components, because floating-point stencil buffers are meaningless.

---

By the way, this whole confusing mess about pixel transfer data type can be completely avoided if you use something like `glTexStorage2D (...)` to ***only*** allocate storage for the texture. `glTexImage2D (...)` does double-duty, allocating storage for a texture LOD and providing a mechanism to initialize it with data. You really do not care about the later part if you are drawing into the texture with an FBO, since that is the only place it gets any data from.

Comment: Both of your suggestions worked.  Thank you very much!  As a side note, for my normal buffer, should I use `GL_RG16F` (half floats), or `GL_RG16I` (signed shorts)?

Comment: @HaydnV.Harach: `GL_RG16I` makes no sense, that is an integer format. What you want is either floating-point or fixed-point. This is because the values in a (normalized) normal will range from [-1,1]. `GL_RG16` (fixed-point) would be sufficient, but since that ranges from [0,1] you will have to apply a scale+bias to re-range it to [-1,1]. I assume you are using the `sqrt` trick to re-construct the missing component of your normal? If you are looking for storage optimized formats that give > 8-bits precision, you could also try RGBA 10:10:10:2 (fixed-point) or RGB 11:11:10 (floating-point).

Comment: I should add to this, if you want a ***signed*** image format that is fixed-point, you need to use what is known as `SNORM` (signed normalized). The typical image format (e.g. `GL_RGB8`) is what is known as `UNORM` (unsigned normalized). `GL_RG16I` is quite different from `GL_RG16_SNORM`, but to understand why you need to understand integer formats vs. fixed-point (normalized). I would suggest reading [this](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#Color_formats), it should explain things a little better.

Comment: Thank you, `GL_RG16_SNORM` is what I meant and was looking for.

Comment: Which would be better, using `GL_RG16_SNORM`/`GL_HALF_FLOAT` and using the `sqrt` trick to reconstruct z, or using `GL_R11F_G11F_B10F` and scaling the value to [-1, +1]?  I imagine the former would give me higher quality, while the latter would require fewer fragment shader instructions...

Comment: Well, the latter does not require scaling. That is a floating-point format so it already has a sign bit. The interesting thing to note about it is that you lose 1-bit of precision on the Z component (this is not so bad if you store your normal buffer in view-space, but might be noticeable in world-space). I would suggest `GL_RGB10_A2` if you really do need the extra precision. I have actually implemented deferred shading using `GL_RGBA8` for the normal buffer with acceptable quality.

Comment: According to the OpenGL wiki, `GL_R11F_G11F_B10F` has no sign bit.

Comment: Just a minor update, I did some experiments.  First off, `GL_RG16_SNORM` would outright fail, so that's not an option.  I tried using `GL_R11F_G11F_B10F`, but in certain spots at certain angles I would end up getting a (0, 0, 0) normal, which is obviously problematic.  Right now I'm using `GL_RG16F` and reconstructing z using the `sqrt` trick, and it's working perfectly.